# FLVPlayback components flicker

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

OK,

I found a flash based video play that will go through a play a series of videos that it read from a XML file. This work for my needs, but it had 1 issue. All it had was a signal custom play/stop button and I need a full control.

So I made a component with the standard PlayPauseButton, StopButton, SeekBar, VolumeBar, and MuteButton FLV components.

So I then go it so the code positioned them where I wanted them. The problem is where i want them is also at the bottom 25px of the video. So I created tween in and out when you mouse over the video framer.

The problem is when the video plays and you mouse over the frame the components components fade-in like they should, but they just flicker constantly.

So i tired a FLVPlayback skin and it work just fine. So I'm wondering if there is any way that i can fix the custom buttons? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the code you wrote for handling the mouse over. It sounds like a "typical" mouse over interaction. For example, mouse over the player and the controls appear, but now the mouse is no longer over the player (it's over the controls), so the controls disappear. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information about your case, but some times we have this issue
When we build button on frame concept with play action  on mouse over 
Just check your button if it is having more than one frame you might be have this case..